# Only show images from an RSS feed with PHP

Tags: php, parsing, rss, feed, simplepie

I'm attempting to parse an rss feed to display images only. I am using a generic wordpress feed and would like to strip out everything that isn't an image.

I've been playing around with [simplepie](http://simplepie.org/) and but haven't been able to find a solid way to display images only.

I found this old simplepie forum post (http://simplepie.org/support/viewtopic.php?id=643) but was unable to get the code working. I suppose it may just be outdated by now but am unsure.

I'm not tied to simplepie but do need to work within php and output html. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried XPath? They say it's pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or something like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file_path);
$imgs = $xml->xpath('/rss/channel/image');
foreach($imgs as $image) {
    echo $image->url;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! Sheesh what was I doing with simplepie SimpleXML is all sorts of awesome

Comment: it's good for reads, adding nodes, and non structural edits, but if you ever want to remove nodes, you will have to use the PHP DOM classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

Using it and [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) should get you what you need.

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('foo.xml');

foreach ($feed->xpath('//img') as $imgnode) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly be using simpleXML and xpath more in the future