# How to parse text and image from complex xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I hope you can help me with that. The XML file looks like this:

```
<channel><item>
<description>
<div>  <a href="http://image.com">
<span>   
<img src="http://image.com" /> 
</span>
</a>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing etc... 
</div>
</description>
</item></channel>
```

I can get the contents of the description tag, but when i do that, i get the whole structure which has lots of css in there and i don't want that.
What i really need is to parse the href link and the Lorem Ipsum text only. I'm trying with simple XML, but can't find out, looks too complicated. Any ideas?

**edit:**
code i use to parse xml

```
$file = new SimpleXMLElement($mydata);
{

    foreach($file->channel->item as $post)
{

    echo $post->description; } }
```

Comment: I also tried to get the attributes using 'attributes()' , but there's no way i can do that. Description tag has no attributes, but more tags inside , like div, a and img. I can't just get the attributes from 'a' and 'img' tags with simple xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code that answears the question.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('myfile.xml');

$descriptions = $xml->xpath('//item/description');

foreach ( $descriptions as $description_node ) {

    $description_dom = new DOMDocument();
    $description_dom->loadHTML( (string)$description_node );

    $description_sxml = simplexml_import_dom( $description_dom );

    $imgs = $description_sxml->xpath('//img');
    $text = $description_sxml->xpath('//div');

    foreach($imgs as $image){

    echo (string)$image['src'];     
       }
    foreach($text as $t){

        echo (string)$t;
       }
    }
```

It is IMSoP's code and i added the `$text = $description_sxml->xpath('//div');` to read the text that is inside the `<div>`.

In my case some of the posts in the xml have multiple `<div>` and `<span>` tags, so to parse all of them i might have to add another `->xpath` for the `<span>` or maybe an `if... else` statement so that if i don't have any content inside `<div>`, echo the `<span>` contents instead.
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: For encoding problems parsing-xml this way, also see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336412/convert-parsed-text-with-php-to-utf-8)

Answer (score 1):

That XML looks very much like an RSS or Atom feed (or an extract from one). The `description` node would commonly be escaped, or placed inside a section marked `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`, which indicates that its contents are to be treated as raw text, even if they contain `<`, `>`, or `&`.

Your sample doesn't indicate that, but if your `echo` is giving you the whole content, including `img` tags etc, then that is what is happening, and your question is similar to [Trying to Parse Only the Images from an RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246656/trying-to-parse-only-the-images-from-an-rss-feed) - you need to grab the whole `description` content, and parse it as a document of its own.

If for some reason the HTML is not being escaped, and is actually being included as a bunch of child nodes inside the XML, then the linked URL can be accessed directly (assuming the structure is always consistent):

```
echo (string)$post->description->div->a['href'];
```

As for the text, SimpleXML will concatenate all text content of a particular element (but not from within its children) if you "cast to string" with `(string)` (`echo` automatically casts to string, but I'm guessing you'll want to do something other than `echo` with it eventually).

In your example, the text you want is inside the first (and only) div, so this would display it:

```
echo (string)$post->description->div;
```

However, you mention "lots of CSS", which I guess you've left out of your example for simplicity, so I'm not sure how consistent your real content is.

Comment: yes, there are many style attributes in there. There are many span tags as well in the text, and some divs too, which i believe might cause some problems.I saw your other post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246656/trying-to-parse-only-the-images-from-an-rss-feed?lq=1 and it seems to work for me, as it gets all the images links. As for the text, it does give me some results (with a little bit of modification) but the problem is i can't read the results due to wrong encoding or something. I wrote this `new DOMDocument('1.0','UTF-8')` but didn't work. what i get is something like ÎÎµÎ³Î¬Î.

Comment: It works fine for images and probably does for the text too. Still encoding is a problem(text is in Greek). I think is caused when i try to get the `$description_dom`. i'll post final code.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to be complicated. <strike>You don't have XML there but html. One difference is that a tag can't contain another tag AND some text in XML. That's why</strike> I'd use the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/de/book.dom.php) of PHP (which I haven't used yet but is similar to pure JavaScript).

This is what I have hacked together (untested):

```
// first create our document
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc->loadHTML("your html here"); // there is also a loadHTMLFile

// this tries to get an a element which has a href and returns that href
function getAHref ( $doc ) {
    // now get all a elements to get the one with a href
    $aElements = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "a" );
    foreach ( $aElements as $a ) {
        // has this element a href? than return
        if ( $a->hasAttribute( "href" ) ) {
            return $a->getAttribute( "href" );
        }
    }
    // failed? return false
    return false;
}

// tires to get the text in the node
// in your example the text isn't wrapped in anything so this is going to be difficult
function getTextFromNode ( $doc ) {
    // get and loop all divs (assuming the text is always a child of a div)
    $divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "div" ); // do we know it's always in that div?
    foreach ( $divs as $div ) {
        // also loop all child nodes to get the text nodes
        foreach ( $div->childNodes as $child ) {
            // is this a text node?
            if ( $child->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE ) {
                // is there something in it (new lines count as text nodes)
                if ( trim( $child->nodeValue ) != "" ) {
                    // *pfew* got it
                    return $child->nodeValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // failed? return false
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I used your script in both the example above and the actual xml file but i don't get any results. Instead i get an error which says "Cannot redeclare getText()", on last line.

Comment: @pano The error message says just whats wrong. PHP has a method build-in that's called getText which I didn't know.

Comment: "a tag can't contain another tag AND some text in XML"? `<foo>bar <child />bob</foo>` is perfectly valid XML.

Comment: @IMSoP You sure? As far as I know many XML parser fail if you parse html because of that reason. Last time I checked even an XMLHttpRequest could not parse html (if you access responseXML; responseText works just fine). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Nemo64 Try it yourself, in whatever XML parser you want, e.g. http://codepad.org/W7AAa1Vh The most common thing that makes (valid) HTML invalid XML is standalone tags, like `<br>`, since in XML **every** tag must be closed, either as `<br></br>` or the short-hand `<br />`. There are other differences - a fragment of HTML often won't constitute a "document" (no single overall containing element), some HTML attributes don't need a value (`<input disabled>`, `<option selected>`, etc). Other times, it's not technically valid as HTML either, but browsers are very forgiving of bad authors.