# Convert parsed text, with php, to utf-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, xml-parsing

In addition to my previous question about [parsing images and text from complex xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299468/how-to-parse-text-and-image-from-complex-xml), only problem about that now is that i don't get the right encoding. Text is in greek, the `xml` file has `utf-8` encoding.
This is the code to parse xml:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('myfile.xml');

$descriptions = $xml->xpath('//item/description');

foreach ( $descriptions as $description_node ) {

    $description_dom = new DOMDocument();
    $description_dom->loadHTML( (string)$description_node );

    $description_sxml = simplexml_import_dom( $description_dom );

    $imgs = $description_sxml->xpath('//img');
    $text = $description_sxml->xpath('//div');

    foreach($imgs as $image){

    echo (string)$image['src'];     
       }

    foreach($text as $t){
    
        echo (string)$t;
       }
    }
```

If i `echo $description_node`,text looks fine, but after i get `$description_dom` with `simplexml_import_dom`it looks like this:
`ÏÎµ Î¹ÏÎ»Î±Î¼Î¹ÎºÎ­Ï ÎºÎ¿Î¹Î½ÏÏÎ·ÏÎµÏ.`Using `mb_convert_encoding` turns it to:
`ÃÂ½ÃÂÃÂ±ÃÂ¹" ÃÂ`. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to add from_encoding param? like `mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-7", "EUC-JP");` also use proper encoding for `DomDocument`

Comment: When you "echo" some string to your browser, make sure you do it from a well formed HTML page with UTF-8 charset specified : `<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
 </head> 
 <body>
<?php echo $text; ?> 
 </body>
</html>` That can already save you from some useless headache.

Comment: `simplexml_load_file` already loads everything in utf-8, try removing the `,'utf-8'` additional conversion maybe

Comment: @PeterM yes, but convert it to utf-8 from ..what?

Comment: @pano encoding from myfile.xml. Maybe it is in different encoding? If so try to convert file *before* passing to `simplexml_load_file`, in that case `simplexml_load_string` should be used. Also try to display raw xml file in browser and see if it's rendered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: after `$description_dom = new DOMDocument();` , i placed this code.

```
$description_html = mb_convert_encoding($description_node, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

Simply converts `html entities` to `UTF-8`. Instead of

```
$description_dom->loadHTML( (string)$description_node );
```

now i load the converted html

```
$description_dom->loadHTML( (string)$description_html );
```

Comment: So, you had special characters encoded as html hex values, etc., right?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the head of your HTML page where you want the text to be displayed :

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
```

This should render the characters properly.

Comment: And make sure you remove $ct=mb_convert_encoding($t, "utf-8")  from your PHP script

Answer (score 0):

Do not convert anything.. just print it with proper declaration

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

This is all you need to do. Do it at the top of your file.

Comment: @pano Start with a very simply php script like `<?php header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"); echo file_get_contents('myfile.xml'); ?> `. After that, start gradually adding your own code and see where it starts to fail.

Comment: already did and it starts to fail after `$description_sxml = simplexml_import_dom( $description_dom );`

Comment: @pano That function should not be a problem at all. Don't have access to documentation right now to confirm.

Comment: If i `echo $description_node` it's ok. If i `echo $description_sxml`, it's not.

Comment: @pano you can avoid most of the stuff by doing    `$imgs = $description_node->xpath('//img');
    $text = $description_node->xpath('//div');`

Comment: sorry, i meant if i `echo` after `$description_sxml`

Comment: thanks for the help. The reason i use `simplexml_import_dom` is because it 'clears' the content to pure text with no styling(images too).